# Can we get the (building) dependencies of some variant in one package in Macports?

Tags: macports

Macports is kinda helpful in lots of way, and I am wondering can we get the dependency list in advance before we install a package with some variants?

For example, what dependencies if I install vim with variants: +huge +tcl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`port deps vim +huge +tcl`

That should list all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Even better:

`port rdeps vim +huge +tcl`

This recursively lists all dependencies, i.e. it also lists the dependencies of the dependencies, whereas `port deps` only lists the dependencies of vim.

If you only want to list the dependencies that you haven't yet installed:

`port list rdepof:vim +huge +tcl and not installed`

`rdepof:vim +huge +tcl` means the recursive dependencies of vim, while `and not installed` filters out the packages you already got.

Alternatively, you can perform a "dry run" installation. This means that the exact installation procedure is followed, only without actually building and installing the packages.

`port -y install vim +huge +tcl`

Answer (score 1):

If you have graphviz installed, you can use https://trac.macports.org/browser/users/eborisch/macports_utils/depTree.py to make a pretty picture showing the tree (what requires what).

```
./depTree.py 'vim +huge+tcl'
```